# Why don't these arrow functions work here within this ES6 class?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I was under the impression that both arrow functions and classes were a feature of ES6. Then why do these arrow functions not work within the class? Would anyone be able to explain what the problem is here? Why doesn't the following work?

```
class Car {
    constructor(brand) {
        this.setBrand(brand);
    }
    
    /*setBrand(brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }*/
    
    /*getBrand() {
        return this.brand;
    }*/
    
    setBrand = brand => this.brand = brand; 
    
    getBrand = () => this.brand;
    
    getAd = () => `${this.brand} is the best brand out there!!`;
}

mycar = new Car("Ford");

console.log( mycar.getAd() );
```

I get the following error.

```
setBrand = brand => this.brand = brand; 
             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
```

Comment: It's not related to arrow functions, `class Thing { a = 1 }` will fail for the same reason.

Comment: Are you sure your environment supports [public class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Browser_compatibility)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for the answer buddy. Unfortunately, I don't quite understand your answer. So what would be the right way to do the above class?

Comment: Either: 1. use a version of Node (12+, see e.g. [node.green](https://node.green/#ESNEXT-candidate--stage-3--instance-class-fields)) that does support it; 2. transpile (using e.g. [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/)) for runtimes that don't support it; or 3. just write regular methods.

Comment: Aaah... Okay! So you are saying that the code itself is correct. But it is not recognised due to my environment limitations. So to make this work, I would have to upgrade Node or transpile using babel. Excellent. Thank you so much!

Comment: You could also move field declaration to constructor `constructor(brand) { this.setBrand = brand => this.brand = brand; ... this.setBrand(brand)}`

Comment: @jonrsharpe It seems that most modern browsers actually support ES6 without the need for transpiling. But since the latest Node LTS version is currently version 10, I assume that most production systems will be using this and so do not support ES6 without transpilers. True?

Comment: The feature you're asking about here is **not** ES6; it's an experimental language feature, at stage 3 with TC39. Per https://node.green Node 10.9+ supports 99% of ES6, everything except "proper tail calls" (10.8 and earlier also lack `Array.prototype.values`).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Wait... Arrow functions are not part of ES6? Or is using them within classes not part of ES6?

Comment: Arrow functions are part of ES6. Instance class fields (whether or not their values are arrow functions, hence [my initial comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63051866/why-arent-the-arrow-functions-working-here-within-the-es6-class?noredirect=1#comment111498680_63051866)) are not.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Interesting!! But weren't classes a part of ES6? If so, what good would they be without any class fields? So how did ES6 classes make it without class fields?